# Random Forest in R - 19 predictors, 1 dependent variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a dataframe (Macro) comprised of one dependent variable (y) and 19 independent variables or features (x).  I'd like to use a random forest algorithm to predict the latest y variable (highlighted in blue) using x values from the same period.

```
 Macro <- read.csv("Input.csv")
x <- Macro[1:13,3:21]  #training data
y <- Macro[1:13,2:2]  #dependent variable
t <- Macro[14:14,2:21]  #period I'd like to predict


rf <- randomForest(x,
                          y,
                          ntree=500,
                          importance=T)

 predict(rf ,t)
```

The above returns a value, but I have a very strong sense that I am approaching the random forest incorrectly and not really using correct procedure or code.  Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: If you want a really good tutorial on random forests in `R`, [Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf) is available for free and chapter 8 covers tree-based methods, including the use of the `randomForest` package in `R`.

Comment: This is not really a well-formed SO question, but for what it's worth the rough structure is right. You train `randomForest` on `x` and `y` and then use `predict` on new data. You are currently saving your forest as `rf` and predicting `cross.sell.rf` though, so there is clearly code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Corrected the SO question

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Macro <- read.csv("Input.csv")

x <- Macro[1:13,3:21]  #training data

y <- Macro[1:13,2]  #dependent variable

t <- Macro[14,3:21]  #period I'd like to predict

rf <- randomForest(x,y,ntree=500,importance=T)

predict(rf ,t)